# How byte array in Java is used to represent a binary data?

Tags: java, byte

I have read that byte array in Java is used to represent a binary data. I am not able to understand this. How byte array can represent a binary data (and which can be transferred over the network and can be constructed back to original form).

Byte can have (integer) values from -128 to 127; so how does a byte array represent a binary data?

Comment: Not sure what the question is...

Comment: Well one byte are 8 bits, which represent the binary data

Comment: Doesn't your hard drive is a Tera-Byte array ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:  I am asking why byte[] arr can represent a binary data; yes nothing magical, but I am not clear :-)

Comment: Java, for several reasons including legacy reason, chose to make `byte` the smallest primitive type which can be used to represent binary data (well `boolean` conceptually represents a bit, but the Java API doesn't use it for binary data).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: So to conclude 1 Byte == 8 bits , and Byte array == stream of bits, and hence represent binary data?

Comment: That's my understanding of it...let someone else shoot me down if I'm off my rocker.

Answer (score 2):

> Byte can be (integer) values `-128 to 127`, so how does a byte
>   array represent a binary data?

Each byte (octet) is a sequence of eight bits, and having sequence of bytes lets us represent binary data of any length (though it's limited to *per 8-bits* increments).

Memory of most modern computers is addressed as a sequence of bytes, network interfaces send packets containing sequences of bytes, hard drives store sequences of bytes (but are addressable only in much larger blocks, say, 4096 bytes).

There is rarely need to access data bit-by-bit, and when needed it can be done with bitwise operators, so no data type for sequence of bits is provided by default.

> So to conclude:
>  
>   `1 Byte == 8 bits`, and `Byte Array == stream of bits`,
>   and hence represent binary data?

Yes. For example: A `Byte Array` of length `2 bytes` is a stream of `16 bits` of `binary data`.